# Delete an item from an Array that is inside an object (redux/typescript/react)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am using a local json file to store some data as the follows:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Sports",
        "todos": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Play Football"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Play Basketball"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Work",
        "todos": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "Study TS"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "title": "Work Hard"
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
```

I made a reducer that takes the two categories above and actually display all these data on the component page.

I am now trying to create another reducer that deletes a certain item from within the todos array that is within each category but I am failing. Here are the actions and the reducers I created so far

```
// actions

export const getCategories = () => {
    return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
        const response = await axios.get<Category[]>(url);

        dispatch({
            type: 'GET_ALL_CATEGORIES',
            payload: response.data
        });
    };
};

export const deleteTodo = (id: number) => {
    return {
        type: 'DELETE_A_TODO',
        payload: { id }
    };
};

// reducers
const categoriesReducer = (state: Category[] = [], action: Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_ALL_CATEGORIES':
            return action.payload;
        case 'DELETE_A_TODO':
            state.forEach(category => {
                return category.todos.filter(
                    todo => todo.id !== action.payload.id
                );
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const reducers = combineReducers<ReduxStoreState>({
    categories: categoriesReducer
});
```

Then inside the component I wired up the deleteTodo action successfully but nothing gets deleted, there is no difference in the state.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in the delete block you dont return anything so you end up with the current state, also `forEach` doesnt return anything

Comment: i don't see you return any new state inside the the delete case

Comment: @plat123456789 when I try to return the new state, it gives me a nasty error that no overload matches this call and that type Todo[][] cannot be assigned to type Category[]

how can I return the same array of categories but with the updates?

Comment: @AsafAviv I used map and it doesn't work too. Check the below comment please.

Comment: @Ahmed Magdy, ok, as you mention, the problem now is type of the state don't match between the original state and the new state you try to set, the question above doesn't include the state interface.

Comment: @plat123456789 
The state interface is simple. It is just a an array of categories.
`
export interface ReduxStoreState {
    categories: Category[];
}
`

How do I make sure the type of the new state I return matches the old state type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
state.forEach(category => {
    return category.todos.filter(
        todo => todo.id !== action.payload.id
    );
});
```

with:

```
return state.map(category => {
  return {
    ...category,
    todos: category.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.payload.id)
  }
})
```

Comment: `forEach` returns `undefined`

Comment: @AsafAviv Thanks, never noticed the forEach usage in the old code.

Comment: @AsafAviv It is required to traversing the category and todos then find the target. The only thing I think could be improved is using immutable data instead of constructing every detail of object each time.  Your code does it well since it achieves part of this work. But I still recommend you to use any immutable lib to make sure it's safe enough.

Comment: Right now you are traversing every todos array on every update even if it's the first item inside the first category object even though in this case it probably doesn't matter because it's small. your solution is more elegant then my solution in this case but a better solution will be to just pass the category index in the payload then we can just iterate over the todos array that contains the todo instead of searching the todo in every todos array to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to return the category name or better the category index with the id in the payload of `deleteTodo` action.

in the current state of your code this is one of the solutions

```
const categoriesReducer = (state: Category[] = [], action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_ALL_CATEGORIES':
      return action.payload
    case 'DELETE_A_TODO': {
      const { id } = action.payload
      const categoryIndex = state
        .findIndex(category => category.todos.some(todo => todo.id === id))

      return state.map((category, i) => i === categoryIndex
        ? {
            ...category,
            todos: category.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id),
          }
        : category
      )
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Now if you return the category index together with the id, we don't need to iterate through every todos array to find the id

```
export const deleteTodo = (id: number, categoryIndex: number) => {
  return {
    type: 'DELETE_A_TODO',
    payload: { id, categoryIndex }
  }
}

const categoriesReducer = (state: Category[] = [], action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_ALL_CATEGORIES':
      return action.payload
    case 'DELETE_A_TODO': {
      const { id, categoryIndex } = action.payload

      return state.map((category, i) => i === categoryIndex
        ? {
            ...category,
            todos: category.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id),
          }
        : category
      )
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling the forEach method does not actually return a new array in your DELETE case, and you are also not returning a new state object, hence the issue.

You need to map over your state and return new category objects with updated todo arrays. This can be achieved using the following code:

```
case 'DELETE_A_TODO':
    return state.map(category => {
        return {
            ...category,
            todos: category.todos.filter(
                todo => todo.id !== action.payload.id
            )
        };
    });
```

Hope that helps.